Solution of $d Y_t/dt = A(t) Y_t, Y_0 = I_d$ is positive definite?
Let $\{A(t)\}_{t \in [0,1]}$ be time-varying symmetric matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. We consider the following ODE for $Y_t \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{d Y_t}{dt} = A(t) Y_t, \quad Y_0 = I_d,
$$
where $I_d$ is the identity matrix. Also, assume that $\sup_{t} \Vert A(t) \Vert_{op} \le a <\infty$. Then, using Picard's iteration one can easily establish the existence and uniqueness of the solution to the above ODE. Moreover, if we have
$$
\tag{2}
A(t_1) A(t_2) = A(t_2) A(t_1)
$$
for all pairs of $t_1, t_2 \in [0,1]$, then using Magnus proposal, it follows that $Y(t) = \exp(\int_{0}^1 A(s) \; ds)$. Therefore, $Y(t)$ is also positive-definite.
Suppose that Condition (2) does not hold. I still want to show that the solution to the ODE (1) enjoys $u^\top Y_t u >0$ (or maybe $\ge 0$) for all unit vector $u$, and for all $t$. Is this true?
My attempt is the following:
Following Picard's iteration we have
$$
Y_t^0 = I_d,
$$
$$
Y_t^{(k+1)} = I_d + \int_{0}^t A(s) Y_s^{(k)}\; ds, \quad k \ge 0.
$$
leveraging this recursion, I was hoping to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} u^\top Y_t^{(k)}u > 0$. However, so far I have been unsuccessful. Is there any counter-example to my claim? Thanks for any help.

Normally, a positive definite matrix $B$ would be defined as a self-adjoint matrix satisfying $u^*Bu\ge 0$. The solution $Y$ will typically not be self-adjoint, not even when the $A(t)$ commute.

@ChristianRemling you are right. However, in this case, I am assuming $A(t)$ to be symmetric as mentioned in the post. In that case, the solution will be positive definite. If we relax the commuting property, we can still ask the question of whether $u^\top Y u>0$ in the limit or not.

If this were true, it would in particular imply that $u^t CD u\ge 0$ for any two positive definite matrices $C,D$ since these have symmetric logarithms and we can then take a piecewise constant $A(t)$.
But this latter claim is clearly false. For example, we can take
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -10 \\ -10 & 110 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 10 \\ 10 & 110 \end{pmatrix} .
$$
Then $e^t_1 CD e_1 =-99$.
